# After clicking "Submit for Review" in TestFlight, status is still "Ready to Submit"

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm submitting my first build for TestFlight beta review and after creating a group, adding 4 team members adding my build, unclicking the box to denote that I'll need login info to test the app, I click "submit for review."

The status at the top of iTunes Connect is still Ready to Submit.

Am I doing something wrong here or is the issue with Apple? All proper docs and Test Information has been filled out as well.

Thanks

---

## Friday night:

Apple finally admit there is a problem:

https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

[image]

---

## Sat morning:

1 - many teams are reporting the problem has cleared overnight.

2 - However FWIW the status board is still indicating a problem.

Comment: I can at least confirm that it is not just you, I have been experiencing the same issue for a few hours - and have heard from other developers in my network that they experience it too.

Comment: Exactly the same for me too. "Submitted" yesterday, but status is just "Ready to Submit" with no option to submit. I've used TF hundreds of times and have not done anything differently this time, so pretty sure TF is currently broken.

Comment: Submitted a bug report: 36453128

Comment: We are facing multiple problems with TestFlight, there is something wrong, we should wait I guess..

Comment: Ah - in our cases apps - betas - have (strangely) moved over to "Waiting for review" ............  friday night

Comment: Personally I will never use the TestFlight service again. I lost days to it. I now use Diawi. Requires UDID but completely straightforward to use otherwise.

Comment: I also experienced this issue and am still having problems submitting a build for beta review - it says there is still a build in review, even though there is not.

I suspect the app/account has been left in an inconsistent state, following the issues over the past few days. I've called developer relations and they have emailed me requesting full technical details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called Apple Developer Support, here were my issues:

1) I had a version that I'd submitted to the App Store and it was Waiting for Review
2) I was trying to submit my first build to *more* than just internal developers (which is what triggers Beta Review)

Once I rectified those, I was able to submit for beta review without problem.

Comment: This particular issue, is not related to the "total disaster" Apple experienced around Jan 11 2018 ....

Answer (score 4):

Appears to be a bug on Apple's side with several cases reported.  Active discussion ongoing here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/288574#288574

No known workarounds at this time.  No ETA for fix at this time.

Bugs have been filed with Apple, support has been called.

Logging out and back in doesn't seem to help.  Clearing local cache, using Safari, etc. doesn't seem to help.

UPDATE: Apple now showing issue on system status page: https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

[image]

Comment: Great work - even worse, one of our beta builds finally changed from "stuck" to ........ "Waiting for review"  :/

Comment: For Saturday morning - the problem has cleared for some people.  FWIW the status board still indicates a problem...

Answer (score 2):

Please logout from iTunesConnect and again login with same credential and try it again it will work for you.

Comment: This actually does somewhat help. Repeatedly logging in and out does seem to trigger it, for some reason?

Comment: hi @cruor99 - do you mean just logging in/out of the web site ?

Comment: @Fattie that is correct. No idea why it works, but at least Apple are aknowledging there’s an issue now